# Http request with PHP Bad Request Error

Tags: php, api, get, request, http-headers

I try to access an API for a web app which will return the data in *json* format. The idea is to configure the header for the *request* to be read properly. An example request provided would be:

```
GET /links/{linkKey}/response HTTP/1.1
Access: *MY SECRET KEY*
Account: *MY ACCOUNT KEY*
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: localhost
User-Agent: YourApp/1.0
```

This example request should return this example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{
    "headers": [
        "column_a",
        "column_b",
        "column_c"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "text 1",
            143.22,
            true
        ],
        [
            "text 2",
            98,
            false
        ],
        [
            "text 3",
            24.9,
            false
        ],
        [
            "value 4",
            242,
            false
        ],
        [
            "value 5",
            32,
            true
        ]
    ],
    "totalRows": 5
}
```

Based on this, I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
// Set header
header('Content-type: application/json');

// See https://app.example.com/#/api
$endpoint = "https://api.example.com/"; // The URL for API access
$api_key = "*MY API_KEY*";
$account_id = "*MY ACCOUNT KEY*";
$access_key = md5($account_id . $api_key);
$link_key = '*MY LINK KEY*'; //Edit your runs inside the app to get their ID

$curl_h = curl_init($endpoint);

curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        "GET /links/" . $link_key . "/latest/result HTTP/1.1\r\n",
        "Access:" . $access_key . "\r\n",
        "Account:" . $account_id . "\r\n",
        "Accept: application/json\r\n",
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n",
        "Host: localhost\r\n",
        "User-Agent: CS-PHP-CLIENT/1.0\r\n",
        "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    )
);

// Store to variable
curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl_h);

curl_close($curl_h);

var_dump($response);
```

This outputs a *400 Bad Request* error in the browser:

```
string(298) "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
"
```

As you can see from above, the regulation of the provider is that the *access_key* must be encrypted using `md5()`. Given that at least `string(298)` appears, I alter the code to `var_dump($curl_h)`, instead of `var_dump($response)`. This eventually outputs an unknown response:

```
resource(2) of type (Unknown)
```

I rewrote the code into something different:

```
<?php
// See https://app.example.com/#/api
$endpoint = "https://api.example.com/"; // The URL for API access
$api_key = "*MY API_KEY*";
$account_id = "*MY ACCOUNT KEY*";
$access_key = md5($account_id . $api_key);
$link_key = '*MY LINK KEY*'; //Edit your runs inside the app to get their ID

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"GET /links/" . $link_key . "/latest/result HTTP/1.1\r\n" .
              "Access:" . $access_key . "\r\n" .
              "Account:" . $account_id . "\r\n" .
              "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
              "Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n" .
              "Host: localhost\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: CS-PHP-CLIENT/1.0\r\n" .
              "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($endpoint, false, $context);

var_dump($file);
```

The following response appears in the browser when I run this code:

```
bool(false)
```

I don't know why this doesn't work.

**NB**: I'm using a localhost on my pc which loads other php files and their respective code correctly.

**API Endpoint**: https://api.example.com/

**Text Encoding**:  All requests must be encoded in UTF-8 - and all responses are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Remove the `"\r\n"` from your headers that you are passing to CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Comment: Hi @CBroe ! I did as you said but I get the same results. Cheers

Comment: The `GET ...` and `hostname` header lines should be created automatically by cURL and file_get_contents, supplying them again might mess things up. // You can always send the request to a URL on your own system first, so that you can log all the request data and check if something doesn’t look right.

Comment: What do you suggest I do? @CBroe I removed the `"Host: localhost\r\n" .` of both code versions and its still the same. Thanks again!

Comment: just a guess, but try to lose the "\r\n" on the headers.

Comment: I already did that @YvesLeBorg